# Tree with more levels

Tags: beamer, spacing, qtree

I'm working with the package `qtree` and I'd loved to make more levels. My code is:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{\secname}
    \Tree [.{L} [.{L1} {\textit{Lag}: \\ ${\textstyle x=y$ \\ \small{C}}  ]
                [.{L2} {\textit{Lag}: \\  ${\textstyle x=z$} ] ]                                                                                                            

\end{frame}
```

I would like to have that `\small{C}` is on e new level under `{\textit{Lag}: \\  ${\textstyle x=y$` but here it is in the same level (I've worked with `\\` to put it on a new line)

I would also want more vspace between the levels, but I can't find how I must do that.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the enhanced `tikz-qtree` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north},
level distance=50pt]
\Tree [. L [.L1 [.{\textit{Lag:}\\ $x=z$} {\small C} ] ]  
                [.L2 {\textit{Lag}:\\ $x=z$} ] ]                                                                                                            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `level distance=<length>` you can control the vertical distance between the anchors of a parent and its children.

Not related to the problem, but `\small` is a font switch not a command with  arguments; also there was no need to use `\textstyle` in your example code.

Comment: @Silke You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. If you consider the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).